# What is the difference between these two MIPS operation?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to two low level code blocks and I know that second one is true. But why first one is errorous? To me, these two seems to work same way. I am not concerned with the == 8 part.

```
if(A[i] == 8) { }

// A stored in $s0
// i stored in $s1

First :
sll $s1, $s1, 2 // i = i * 4
lw $t0, $s0, $s1 // we have A[i] in $t0

Second :
sll $s1, $s1, 2 // i = i * 4
add $s0, $s0, $s1 // we have the address of A[i]
lw $t0, 0($s0) or lw $t0, $s0, 0 // we have A[i] in $t0
```

Comment: `lw $t0, $s0, $s1` <-- There's no such form of `lw`. So the simple answer to _"why first one is errorous?"_ is: because you're trying to use an instruction that doesn't exist.

Comment: `lw` is a type-I instruction, despite its name having no `i` suffix like the MIPS naming convention. That means it must be used with an immediate, not 3 registers